# Set default window size for Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, windows-10, minecraft-launcher

I'm annoyed that every time I launch Minecraft, it's a tiny window (854x480 pixels + window borders) that I have to resize. I don't want to run the game in fullscreen, or maximized, but I do want the window larger than that.

And since it's difficult to scale the window precisely, my screenshots end up all different sizes.

I don't see anything in the Options GUI.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's easier than in the self-answer. In the launcher, you can click on "Installations", then on the profile you want (default is "Latest release") and then set a resolution in there.

Comment: Easier is a subjective term :P I found the text file easier, but this is probably better for most people. Thanks!

Comment: In theory editing this file isn't supported. If you for example get any bugs after doing that, they are automatically invalid on the bug tracker.

Answer (score 2):

Well, never mind. I figured it out.

Edit `.minecraft/options.txt` and set the `overrideWidth` and `overrideHeight` values to your desired values. This will be the size of the game screen itself (so the actual window will be slightly larger with your OS's borders).

**Make sure the game and launcher are closed while you are editing this file**, otherwise it will reset them to 0.